# How to estimate theoretical RTT of a message over socket?

Tags: python, sockets, port

I am working on a project that uses socket programming in Python. Right now I am trying to configure this project to run over the internet, which basically means that the client script can be run from anywhere, on condition that it is provided with the public IP of the machine running the server script. Using port-forwarding, I eventually got this to work, and now the client and server can be run on 2 different machines. However, I want to see if the RTT can be improved. Is there a way to theoretically calculate RTT of a message being sent over a socket, if I know the message size and the internet speeds at the client and the server machine, or any such additional data? I basically want to calculate the least possible value for RTT with a given socket setup, and then check if the actual measured time is close to that. If not, then there is some inefficiency somewhere in my code affecting performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no theoretical way to calculate RTT as it depends on the hardware in between you and the other computer. However, you can just `ping` the computer and find out. Here I use 8.8.8.8 as an example - it's a Google server.

```
C:\> ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=118
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=118

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 14ms, Maximum = 14ms, Average = 14ms
```

This command sends a packet to the other computer which sends a packet back, and then it measures how long it took. Windows's version of `ping` repeats 4 times. Other versions might repeat until you stop them with Ctrl-C.